# Configure GCP PubSub subscription configured by Eventarc

Tags: terraform

I'm using Eventarc to connect an GCS event to a Cloudrun service. Eventarc, behind the scenes, will also configure a Pubsub subscription. Is it possible to modify some of the parameters in said subscription via some mechanism known to Eventarc using Terraform?